# How to access variables across Javascript files with babel?

Tags: javascript, module, global-variables, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to migrate my code from `ES5` to `ES6` and use `babel`. I use the module pattern quite a bit in my code, such that if I have a module like `apple` I'll do something like this:

```
var appleModule = (function() {
    var yummy = true;
    var eat = function() { }

    return { "eat": eat }
})();
```

and then access `appleModule` in a different file. However, when moving everything from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/apple.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/banana.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.25/browser.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="/scripts/apple.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="/scripts/banana.js"></script>
```

I can no longer access `appleModule` in different files. I get a `ReferenceError` saying it doesn't exist. How do access variables across files with babel and ES6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please actually read the documentation for [babel-browser](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/)

> **Not intended for serious use**
>   Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts server-side. See [setup build systems](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#build-systems) for more information.

You're not supposed to use babel-browser like that in a production environment. Not even in a development one, really.

Instead, setup a proper build step for your code to transpile and bundle your code.

You don't even have to create your own modules like that

**a.js**

```
var yummy = true;
var eat = function(){};

export var eat;
```

**b.js**

```
import {eat} from './a.js';
```

Comment: Wouldn't the same issue still exist anyway? Also, I was only using babel-browser for development. I'd compile everything before releasing it of course.

Comment: @RyanPeschel no. Use the ES6 [module system](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 exporting only takes the exported parts and everything else is practically equivalent of being in a function, to import appleModule

```
export var appleModule = (function() {
var yummy = true;
var eat = function() { }

return { "eat": eat }
})();

import  {appleModule as appleModule}  from './apple';
```