# Why is module import crashing Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, module

I'm working on refactoring a simple use of the SunCalc.js code. Initially I had all of the SunCalc code in my `background.js` (and the extension worked), but I'd like to put the SunCalc code in a separate file `suncalc.js`.

Here is the new `background.js`:

```
import {sunModule as sunModule} from "./suncalc.js";

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    alert("Running.");
    // Note that this may take a second:
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(wasSuccessful, notSuccessful);
});

function wasSuccessful(position) {
    alert("Here");
    var theDate = new Date();
    var times = SunCalc.getTimes(new Date(), position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    if ((theDate <= times.sunrise) || (times.sunset <= theDate)) {
        alert("It's night.");
    } else {
        alert("It's day.");
    };
}

function notSuccessful(err) {
    alert("Not Successful.");
}
```

And here is the suncalc.js module:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * SunCalc
 *
 * SunCalc is a tiny BSD-licensed JavaScript library for calculating sun
 * position, sunlight phases (times for sunrise, sunset, dusk, etc.), moon
 * position and lunar phase for the given location and time, created by
 * Vladimir Agafonkin (http://agafonkin.com/en, https://github.com/mourner) as
 * a part of the [SunCalc.net project](http://suncalc.net).
 *
 * Most calculations are based on the formulas given on the site Astronomy
 * Answers and Wikipedia.
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 export var sunModule = (function () { 'use strict';

 // shortcuts for easier to read formulas

 var PI   = Math.PI,
 sin  = Math.sin,
 cos  = Math.cos,
 tan  = Math.tan,
 asin = Math.asin,
 atan = Math.atan2,
 acos = Math.acos,
 rad  = PI / 180;

 // sun calculations are based on http://aa.quae.nl/en/reken/zonpositie.html formulas


 // date/time constants and conversions

 var dayMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
 J1970 = 2440588,
 J2000 = 2451545;

 function toJulian(date) { return date.valueOf() / dayMs - 0.5 + J1970; }
 function fromJulian(j)  { return new Date((j + 0.5 - J1970) * dayMs); }
 function toDays(date)   { return toJulian(date) - J2000; }


 // general calculations for position

 var e = rad * 23.4397; // obliquity of the Earth

 function rightAscension(l, b) { return atan(sin(l) * cos(e) - tan(b) * sin(e), cos(l)); }
 function declination(l, b)    { return asin(sin(b) * cos(e) + cos(b) * sin(e) * sin(l)); }

 function azimuth(H, phi, dec)  { return atan(sin(H), cos(H) * sin(phi) - tan(dec) * cos(phi)); }
 function altitude(H, phi, dec) { return asin(sin(phi) * sin(dec) + cos(phi) * cos(dec) * cos(H)); }

 function siderealTime(d, lw) { return rad * (280.16 + 360.9856235 * d) - lw; }

 function astroRefraction(h) {
     if (h < 0) // the following formula works for positive altitudes only.
     h = 0; // if h = -0.08901179 a div/0 would occur.

     // formula 16.4 of "Astronomical Algorithms" 2nd edition by Jean Meeus (Willmann-Bell, Richmond) 1998.
     // 1.02 / tan(h + 10.26 / (h + 5.10)) h in degrees, result in arc minutes -> converted to rad:
     return 0.0002967 / Math.tan(h + 0.00312536 / (h + 0.08901179));
 }

 // general sun calculations

 function solarMeanAnomaly(d) { return rad * (357.5291 + 0.98560028 * d); }

 function eclipticLongitude(M) {

     var C = rad * (1.9148 * sin(M) + 0.02 * sin(2 * M) + 0.0003 * sin(3 * M)), // equation of center
     P = rad * 102.9372; // perihelion of the Earth

     return M + C + P + PI;
 }

 function sunCoords(d) {

     var M = solarMeanAnomaly(d),
     L = eclipticLongitude(M);

     return {
         dec: declination(L, 0),
         ra: rightAscension(L, 0)
     };
 }


 var SunCalc = {};


 // calculates sun position for a given date and latitude/longitude

 SunCalc.getPosition = function (date, lat, lng) {

     var lw  = rad * -lng,
     phi = rad * lat,
     d   = toDays(date),

     c  = sunCoords(d),
     H  = siderealTime(d, lw) - c.ra;

     return {
         azimuth: azimuth(H, phi, c.dec),
         altitude: altitude(H, phi, c.dec)
     };
 };


 // sun times configuration (angle, morning name, evening name)

 var times = SunCalc.times = [
     [-0.833, 'sunrise',       'sunset'      ],
     [  -0.3, 'sunriseEnd',    'sunsetStart' ],
     [    -6, 'dawn',          'dusk'        ],
     [   -12, 'nauticalDawn',  'nauticalDusk'],
     [   -18, 'nightEnd',      'night'       ],
     [     6, 'goldenHourEnd', 'goldenHour'  ]
 ];

 // adds a custom time to the times config

 SunCalc.addTime = function (angle, riseName, setName) {
     times.push([angle, riseName, setName]);
 };


 // calculations for sun times

 var J0 = 0.0009;

 function julianCycle(d, lw) { return Math.round(d - J0 - lw / (2 * PI)); }

 function approxTransit(Ht, lw, n) { return J0 + (Ht + lw) / (2 * PI) + n; }
 function solarTransitJ(ds, M, L)  { return J2000 + ds + 0.0053 * sin(M) - 0.0069 * sin(2 * L); }

 function hourAngle(h, phi, d) { return acos((sin(h) - sin(phi) * sin(d)) / (cos(phi) * cos(d))); }

 // returns set time for the given sun altitude
 function getSetJ(h, lw, phi, dec, n, M, L) {

     var w = hourAngle(h, phi, dec),
     a = approxTransit(w, lw, n);
     return solarTransitJ(a, M, L);
 }


 // calculates sun times for a given date and latitude/longitude

 SunCalc.getTimes = function (date, lat, lng) {

     var lw = rad * -lng,
     phi = rad * lat,

     d = toDays(date),
     n = julianCycle(d, lw),
     ds = approxTransit(0, lw, n),

     M = solarMeanAnomaly(ds),
     L = eclipticLongitude(M),
     dec = declination(L, 0),

     Jnoon = solarTransitJ(ds, M, L),

     i, len, time, Jset, Jrise;


     var result = {
         solarNoon: fromJulian(Jnoon),
         nadir: fromJulian(Jnoon - 0.5)
     };

     for (i = 0, len = times.length; i < len; i += 1) {
         time = times[i];

         Jset = getSetJ(time[0] * rad, lw, phi, dec, n, M, L);
         Jrise = Jnoon - (Jset - Jnoon);

         result[time[1]] = fromJulian(Jrise);
         result[time[2]] = fromJulian(Jset);
     }

     return result;
 };
 // export as Node module / AMD module / browser variable
 if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined') module.exports = SunCalc;
 else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) define(SunCalc);
 else window.SunCalc = SunCalc;

}());
```

I've been trying to implement the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314611/how-to-access-variables-across-javascript-files-with-babel) as well as [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), but whenever I include the import line in `background.js`, the extension doesn't work at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Modules aren't supported yet in the background page, see  https://crbug.com/728377, https://crbug.com/738739

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh that's weird. Is it recommended that I just shove the entire module down at the bottom of `background.js`?

Comment: Either that or use webpack etc.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @wOxxOm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wOxxOm said, if you want to use ES6 modular system, you have to use Webpack or Rollup bundlers.
Otherwise, you can refactor these modules to using globals and put them into manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js", "module1.js", "module2.js"]
}
```

An alternate way is to create **background.html** file and specify all needed scripts (as usual, via `<script>` tag). 
Manifest will be like:

```
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
}
```